# Combinations of all characters in strings in an arraylist in Java, Set multiplication

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an arraylist (size unknown) of Strings (string lengths are not same).
I need to print the combinations of all the characters in the Strings(specific condition), no repetition. It is more or like combination of elements in Sets as in Mathematics.

Condition:

1. Output String length --> size of given arraylist (in the below example, since the ArrayList size is 3, output strings should be of length 3).
2. Each character of the new Strings formed, must take each character from each of the string in the ArrayList.

Here is an example:
Array List is sample: `["abc", "de", "fg"]`

(number of output strings: 3(size of 1st string)*2(size of 2nd string)*2(size of 3rd string) = 12)

Output should be:

```
["adf", 
"adg", 
"aef", 
"aeg", 
"bdf", 
"bdg", 
"bef", 
"beg", 
"cdf", 
"cdg", 
"cef", 
"ceg"]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please provide some more information and your code - what did you try so far and what is your specific problem?

Comment: "No repetition, no duplicates." do you know that, as in your example, all the letters are unique?

Comment: I have not tried any code, since I have not able to write an algorithm.

Comment: Basically the `Cartesian product` of the letters in the words.

Comment: All letters in the Strings need not be and will not be unique. I mean to say that while forming a new string, take each character from each string in the arraylist. Print all combinations

Comment: [Guidelines for asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/7098259)

Comment: This is not a homework, it is a part of the project that I am currently handling. @sarkasronie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no one is supposed to give you the actual code for your homework.

Here is the basic idea on how it looks like conceptually:

This can be done recursively by (pseudo-code of course):

```
String[] allCombinations(String[] input) {
    if (input is empty) {
        return [ "" ]
    }

    String[] result

    String[] childrenCombinations = allCombinations(input[1:])
    foreach char c in input[0] {
        foreach string s in childrenCombinations {
            result += ( c + s )
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Of course this is a very naive recursive logic with a lot of unnecessary object creation.  However it give you an idea how the algorithm looks like.  You may think of area of optimization after you understand the logic

Comment: Interested to know reason of downvote. Just because I give a valid algorithm but without actual Java code?

Comment: String[] childrenCombinations = allCombinations(input[1:]) -- In the above line, can you help me with allCombinations(input[1:]) -> what does this (input[1:]) signify?

Comment: @Raghavendra it is a common notation for creating sub list, based on content of index 1 to the end

Comment: @AdrianShum - This is not a homework, it is a part of usecase scenario of the project that I am handling now. Anyways thanks for the algorithm, it solved my problem.

Comment: @Raghavendra “homework” here does not only includes homework literally, but more about how question should be asked in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("d", "e");
String[][] AB = a.stream().flatMap(ai -> b.stream().map(bi -> new String[] { ai, bi })).toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(AB));
```

Comment: "I have an arraylist (size unknown)"... the code needs to work for an arbitrary number of strings